# opening a file and reading data

Tags: python, filereader

So I am using these lines of code to read an Excel file.

```
fin=open("C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Python Coding\bodyfat.csv",'rU')
fin.readline()
```

However I keep getting this error statement and I have no idea what is going on

```
>>> fin=open("C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Python Coding\bodyfat.csv",'rU')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rU') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\Python Coding\x08odyfat.csv'
>>> fin.readline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fin' is not defined
```

Any idea on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error occurs because, in standard Python strings, backslashes do interesting things to the characters that follow them (see [the documentation on string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) for details):

```
>>> "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Python Coding\bodyfat.csv"
'C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\Python Coding\x08odyfat.csv'
                                         # ^ what?
```

The second error occurs because, after the first error occurs, `fin` is never assigned.

The simplest fix is to use "raw strings", prefixed with an `r`, to indicate that backslashes should be treated as normal characters:

```
>>> r"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Python Coding\bodyfat.csv"
'C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\Python Coding\\bodyfat.csv'
```

*(Don't worry about the doubling, that's just Python's way of indicating that those are literal backslashes, rather than escaping the characters that follow.)*

Also, you should use the `with` "context manager" for file handling:

```
with open(r"...") as fin:
    line = fin.readline()
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not escaping string backslashes properly. Notice in the traceback it says "Coding\x08odyfa". You can use raw strings

```
r"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\Python Coding\bodyfat.csv"
```

or escape the escape char

```
"C:\\Users\\Student\\Desktop\\Python Coding\\bodyfat.csv"
```